# $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1^n+2^n+…+n^n) /n^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{n-k}{n})^n=e^{-k}$$
We can predict that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1^n+2^n+…+n^n) /n^n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-k}=\frac{e}{e-1}$$
However, I think the solution is NOT strict enough. Although I have a rigorous proof for this, I want a easier solution.$$$$My solution as follows:

Comment: Or even better (I cannot cast a second vote) [How to evaluate $ \lim \limits_{n\to \infty} \sum \limits_ {k=1}^n \frac{k^n}{n^n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164074)

Answer (score 0):

$\bf{Solution\quad by\quad the\quad poster:}$ $$$$Firstly, it is trivial that the limit exists, then I try to use  $\epsilon-N$ language for my proof.
$$$$ $\forall N<n, N\in\mathbb{N}$ ,we denote that $$A=\sum_{i=1}^{n-N-1}(\frac{i}{n})^n$$ and $$B=\sum_{i=N}^{n}(\frac{i}{n})^n$$ 
Let $N$ be fixed , when $n\to\infty$, $$A<\dfrac{\int_0^{n-N}x^n dx}{n^n}=\dfrac{(n-N)^{n+1}}{(n+1)n^n}<(1-\frac{N}{n})^n=e^{\ln (1-\frac{N}{n})}<e^{-N}$$
Then we deduce that $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N_0\in\{1,2,\cdots,n\}:A<e^{-N}<\epsilon$
$$$$As for $B$, we have:
$$|e^k(1-\frac{k}{n})^n-1|=|e^{k+n\ln (1-\frac{k}{n})}-1|=\frac{k^2}{2n}+o(\frac{1}{n})<\frac{c_kN^2}{n}<\epsilon\text{ ,as $n$ is big enough.}$$
We have$$|(1-\frac{k}{n})^n-e^{-k}|<\frac{c_kN^2}{n}e^{-k}<\epsilon e^{-k}\text{ ,$c_k$ is a constant}$$
Then, we have 
$$|B-\sum_{k=0}^N e^{-k}|<\sum_{k=0}^N|(1-\frac{k}{n})^n-e^{-k}|<\epsilon \sum_{k=0}^Ne^{-k}<\frac{e}{e-1}\epsilon$$
We deduce that $$|(1^n+2^n+…+n^n) /n^n-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{-k}|<C\epsilon \text{ ,for some $C=$ constant}$$
Hence, when $n\to\infty$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1^n+2^n+…+n^n) /n^n=\frac{e}{e-1}$$

Comment: The question has already been posted on Quora. Link: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-find-the-limit-of-a-sequence-1-n-2-n-n-n-n-n-as-n. But I think the solution there is not what I want, since we cannot add the limits when there are infinite series.

Comment: For the record, you are right in pointing out that you cannot simply interchange the order of the limit and sum when the number of terms grows with $n$, as the Quora answers seem to do.